# SQL Server : drop default constraint, alter column and recreate constraint

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible and how to alter column with default constraint ?

The problem: I want to invoke this alter:

For example

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE 
    ALTER COLUMN MY_COLUMN nvarchar(1024); --(was varchar)
```

But this code throws an exception:

> [S0001][5074] Line 1: The object 'DF__MY_TABLE __MY_COL__2A563856' is dependent on column 'MY_COLUMN '.

I know how to search for that constraint:

```
 select c.name, col.name 
 from sys.default_constraints c
 inner join sys.columns col on col.default_object_id = c.object_id
 inner join sys.objects o  on o.object_id = c.parent_object_id
 inner join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
 where o.name = 'MY_TABLE' and col.name = 'MY_COLUMN'
```

and now I not only want to drop the constraint that blocks the execution of the above alter but also recreate this constraint.

I have 100 columns like that so I want to write some procedure or function and call it 100 times in script for each table and command separately.

Moreover some columns would have default values like '' or '-' or no default value at all. It is important that after scripts execution all constraints would be as before execution and none of them would be missing.

Comment: As a side note, when you do recreate your `CONSTRAINT`s I strongly recommend giving them meaningful names.

Comment: What about other types of constraints such as indexes and / or check constraints?

Comment: Just run `ALTER TABLE dbo.MY_TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT DF__MY_TABLE __MY_COL__2A563856;` - then the constraint is dropped and you can alter your column as you want to

Comment: Primary keys or indexes will not be present as those are only varchar fields, they may. They might however be not null constraints. @marc_s and when I drop it how would I know that that column had '-' default value ? After my alters it still must have all constraints that it had prevoiusly.

Comment: I think you need to be clearer about how you find these 100 columns? Are they on one table, different tables, different names, different data types?

Comment: If you don't know what constraints you have - script out the table *before* changing anything, in SSMS, to get a `CREATE TABLE ....` script, including all relevant constraints. Then re-apply the constraint (preferably with a **more useful name (!)** after you have altered your table

Comment: :Charlieface different tables different columns. I want to invoke my_alter_function(tableName, columnName) thats all. @marc_s there are no default constraints in create table scripts, there is only something like that: LAST_USERNAME          varchar(256)  default '' not null,

Comment: Consider using database projects/DACPACs for this kind of deployment; the heavy lifting of comparing, dropping and re-scripting things has already been done there (although I can't guarantee it covers this particular case, but I think it does). Without this (or front-end support) you need some programming, and I don't think I have to tell you T-SQL is not the world's greatest programming language.

Comment: @michealAtmi you cannot run DDL in an SQL Server function.

Comment: OK how would I find these columns? All you have above is `where o.name = 'MY_TABLE' and col.name = 'MY_COLUMN'` which is only going to find one column

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I've just hit this same issue trying to script updates to an old database schema that still uses text, ntext and image types [which have long been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=The%20ntext%2C%20text%2C%20and%20image%20data%20types%20will%20be%20removed%20in%20a%20future%20version%20of%20SQL%20Server).

This script drops the existing default constraint on every column of that type, alters the column, then recreates the default as it existed originally. It could be modified for other implicitly convertable type changes by using type identifiers as found in `sys.types`:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = string_agg(
    -- add drop default constraint if one exists
    case when dc.object_id is not null then 
        'alter table [dbo].[' + t.name + '] drop constraint [' + dc.name + ']' + char(10) 
    else '' end +

    -- alter table
    'alter table [' + t.name + '] alter column [' + c.name + '] ' + 
    case
        when type.name = 'text' then 'varchar(max);'
        when type.name = 'ntext' then 'nvarchar(max);'
        when type.name = 'image' then 'varbinary(max);' end +

    -- readd constraint with the same name and conditions as it had originally
    case when dc.object_id is not null then 
        char(10) + 'alter table [dbo].[' + t.name + '] add  constraint [' + dc.name + ']  default ' + isnull(dc.definition, '(null)') + ' for [' + c.name + ']' + char(10)
    else '' end, ''
)
from sys.tables t 
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id 
inner join sys.types type on c.system_type_id = type.system_type_id
left join sys.default_constraints dc on dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id and dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
where type.name in ('text', 'ntext', 'image')

print @sql -- note that this may be truncated if too long

-- uncomment this if you're happy with the results:
-- exec sp_executesql @sql
```